# String interned to two String objects but same behaviour and Value

Tags: java, string, object, reference, immutability

String is Immutable (Fact)

Lets say I have two objects of string given below:

```
String str1 = new String("dave");
String str2 = new String("dave");
```

While compiling, Interning of string objects happens. And according to Wikipedia, It says "string interning is a method of storing only one copy of each distinct string value, which must be immutable. All compile-time constant strings in Java are automatically interned using this method."

If that's a case, then what would happen to my two references str1 and str2 ? To which object they will point out once compiled ?

I hope its valid question, otherwise correct me, I'm confused little bit.

Comment: `str1` and `str2` are **not** compile time constants, since they are both instantiated with `new`

Comment: @khelwood, So you mean both references would skip Interning while compilation. And nothing will happen to the two similar objects. They will exist  individually with their respective references. Is it so ?

Comment: The two string literals `"dave"` may be interned, but the objects held by `str1` and `str2` are different objects each created by `new` at runtime. They do indeed exist individually.

Comment: In other words `str1 != str2 && str2 != "dave", && str2 != "dave"`

Comment: Doesn't `System.out.println(str1 == str2);` answer your question? `new String("dave")` is **NOT** the same as `"dave"`.

Comment: @khelwood, Okay Agree, it creates two new object and totally independent to each other. But When we use like String str = "dave", so it means the  String object with value "dave" already exist in pool. Even if we define it first time, then when this object was created ?How we are able to refer it directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Below both str1 and str2 are created on heap, because you are creating them at run time. Even both objects are created at different references.

```
String str1 = new String("dave");
String str2 = new String("dave");
```

> Even str1 == str2 will return false. Their values are same but they are two different objects on heap.

---

However if you create the object at compile time, as example

```
String str1="dave";
String str2="dave";
```

> then str1 == str2 will return true, because both these objects are
>   part of same reference created at compile time in string pool.

When we use double quotes to create a String, it first looks for String with same value in the String pool, if found it just returns the reference else it creates a new String in the pool and then returns the reference.

Comment: Can you please check my last posted comment above ?

Comment: I guess, I answered your question now. Just check my updated answer.  Compile time and run time- that's two different things for String Objects.

Comment: "because both these objects are part of same reference and that's string literal pool"..How ? str1 and str2 are difference references and pointing to same object ..!! That's why they are returning true. I'm asking, When these were created ?

Comment: So what makes a difference, Second times its okay I understand. But what about first time. So either we write String str = "dave or String str = new String("dave"), both are the same thing..NO ?

Comment: No. They are not same. String str = "dave  object is created at compile time in String pool and when you mention new String("dave")  it's created at run time on heap.

Comment: That's makes sense...!! :)